# Error creating bean with name 'authenticationSuccessHandler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/application-security.xml]

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting the following error:

```
 Caused by: 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'authenticationSuccessHandler' defined 
 in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/application-security.xml]: 
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
 nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
 qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at 
 least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
 annotations: {}
```

My bean in my IDE looks like so:
[image]

LoginSuccessHandler

```
public class LoginSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginSuccessHandler.class);
    
    private UserDto user = (UserDto) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    
    public LoginSuccessHandler(String defaultTargetUrl, HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(defaultTargetUrl);
        this.request = request;
    }
```

When I hover over it it says `String defaultTargetUrl ???` and `HttpServletRequest ???`

In my application-security.xml file I have it defined like so:

```
<security:form-login login-page="/logon.do"
                         login-processing-url="/logon.do"
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                         authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
                         username-parameter="username"
                         password-parameter="password"/>
    <!-- Users limited to one login at a time -->
    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
    </security:session-management>
    
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" delete-cookies="true"
                     invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" />
    <!-- enable CSRF -->
    <security:csrf disabled="false"/>
</security:http>
```

This part of the error has me very confused.

`No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available:`

This is a compilation error. Any advice with be greatly appreciated.

-----------------------Update one------------------------

I removed the constructors parameters and the error went away. However now I am getting an error saying: `.LoginSuccessHandler]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`

The bean looks the same but I read `The determineTargetUrl method is the only thing which uses it and request is one of its arguments. Either use a <constructor-arg> in the xml and pass the value for defaultUrl or remove it as an argument and get it elsewhere.` But I am not sure where to put it.

Right now the null pointer exception is on this line after removing the constructor:

```
private UserDto user = (UserDto) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

I am also getting and error saying:

```
caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name
```

`'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenti cationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean  'authenticationSuccessHandler' while setting bean property   'authenticationSuccessHandler'; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating  bean with name 'authenticationSuccessHandler' defined in ServletContext  resource [/WEB-INF/config/application-security.xml]:`

------------------------Update 2---------------------------

I did the following:

```
public class LoginSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginSuccessHandler.class);
    
    @Override
    protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        
        UserDto user = (UserDto) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Before I was getting a nullPointerException because `UserDto user = (UserDto) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();` before the method. Now I am getting an error saying:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:No bean named 
'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' available: Did 
you forget to add a global <authentication-manager> element to your 
configuration (with child <authentication-provider> elements)? 
Alternatively you can use the authentication-manager-ref attribute on 
your <http> and <global-method-security> elements.
```

Comment: Your LoginSuccessHandler is flawed. You should not have request and user fields there because success handler is a singleton bean.

Comment: No, tutorial does not have those fields. What are you trying to do with the handler anyway?

Comment: @holmis83 it looks like the issue was the constructor, I deleted it. But now I get an error saying `Error creating bean with name authenticationSuccessHandler defined in ServletContext resourc`  but I am scanning it in my web.xml file. `/WEB-INF/config/application-security.xml</param-value>`

Comment: @holmis83 please see update 1

Comment: @holmis83 I am trying to have validate different things about the users account and return the path necessary. Example, a user needs to update their password, or that are fine and they go to the home page.

Comment: @holmis83 please see update 2

Comment: @Drew1208: You are setting property in LoginSuccessHandler but to instantiate LoginSuccessHandler bean you need to set constructor-arg(Constructor-based Dependency Injection) in the bean definition as <constructor-arg type = "java.lang.String" value = "false"/> and why you need to set HttpServletRequest request object as this will be available in the onAuthenticationSuccess() method

Answer (score 1):

The first error is the one on the class you wrote. The constructor ask for a String and for a HTTPSession.

- The String can be set as an attribute
- The HTTPSession should not be used as a spring bean as Spring declare Singleton and Session depends on user.

The second error means you forgot to provide a authentication manager. You can add one with:

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

where userDetailsService is a bean that map a name to a UserDetails. 
Spring provides some implementation like  `InMemoryUserDetailsManager`, `JdbcUserDetailsManager` or `LdapUserDetailsService`.